# how to make 69.99*100 print 6999 instead of 6998?

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, double

I want to have the right 6999 but the code prints 6998, is there any way to implement it in C/C++?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
 double x = 69.99;
 int xi = x*100;
 cout << xi << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: For a lot of detail on this, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken). In this specific case you could use [std::round](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) in the form of `int xi = std::round(x*100);` but depending on your actual situation the edge case subtleties may be trickier to root out.

Comment: If you are dealing in 2 decimal points and always 2 decimal points, for example dollar money amounts, use integers and [fixed point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) so that you never have to deal with imprecision.

Comment: your code is not C. And there's no language called C/C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler is probably using the [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) double precision floating point format for representing the C++ data type `double`. This format cannot represent the number `69.99` exactly. It [is stored as](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=054057046057057) `69.989999999999994884`. When you multiply this value with `100`, the result is slightly smaller than `6999`.

When implicitly converting floating-point numbers to integers, the number is always rounded towards zero (positive numbers get rounded down, negative ones get rounded up).

If you don't want to always round the result towards zero, you can change the line

`int xi = x*100;`

to

`long xi = lround( x*100 );`

which will not always round the number towards zero, but will instead always round it to the nearest integer.

Note that you must `#include <cmath>` to be able to use [`std::lround`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round).

Comment: Minor: I'd go with `long xi = lround( x*100 );` and avoid `int` truncation.

Comment: @JaMiT `69.99 * 100` only amplifies by 0.5 least significant bits.  Still eough with `int` trucation to end with unacceptable results.

Comment: @JaMiT Fair enough - many views are possible.  Yet precsison of `double` is best viewed as [relative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place), it is _floating_, not _fixed_ point after all.

Comment: @chux: I have changed the `int` variable to `long` to prevent truncation, as you suggested.